# student list on button click in swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my main.storyboard there has "all student" button. I need to open student list when "all student" button will be clicked.

Students are already saved in realm db. So far I've done below:-

1. Have dragged view controller from object library and have placed in empty space.
2. Have also dragged table view and table view cell inside view controller.
3. Created a modal segue from "all student" button to this view controller.
4. Have given cell identifier to "Cell" and segue identifier to "rList"

In vieController, I've made the following changes:-

```
Class vieController: UIvieController, UITextfieldDelegate
```

to below:

```
Class vieController: UIvieController, UITextfieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource.
```

but getting below error in `viewDidLoad`:

> fatal error: unexpectedlyfound nil while unwrapping an optional value

on below line:

```
table1.dataSource = self
```

Not getting how I'll achieve this student list. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show the screen shot of error

Comment: share ur code plz.

Answer (score 3):

Delete the line **table1.dataSource = self**

Then go to the Connections Inspectors of tableView from storyboard
after that drag the dataSource to your viewController

also make sure that your tableView outlet is connected properly.

I hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

First, you should check to make sure that you have a proper table view outlet in your view controller. I show in my screenshot how the table view outlet is created.

[image: How to add a table view outlet.]

You can then use

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

in your viewDidLoad.

---

As far as getting the data to show, you can put your data into an array property in your view controller.

If the data is being loaded from the network, then the table view should be reloaded using `tableView.reloadData()` after the data has loaded.

The other pieces that you seem to be missing are the required data source methods for a UITableViewDataSource.

There are two functions that are required and they belong in your view controller.

I’ve provided minimal outlines below to get you started.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    // The cell identifier is set in your storyboard.
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Do stuff like set values on labels in the cell.
    cell.label.text = “text to display”
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
    // Return the number of cells to be displayed.
    return 10
}
```